# Function can't find variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was messing around with my game's CSS, and now I get a variable error for every button I click that calls a function, saying it can't find the variable.

I deleted the CSS and everything has changed, but the game is still broken.
I don't know whats wrong, so I have provided a link to download the code.

**The error:** `reference error: can't find variable: duckClick`

---

**Related JavaScript:**

```
var ducks = 0;
function duckClick(number){
ducks = ducks + number;
document.getElementById("ducks").innerHTML = ducks;
```

This calls `duckClick` but I'm getting a error saying it can't find it.

```
<button onclick="duckClick(1)">Find Duck</button>
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant bits of code here?

Comment: i don't know what they are but i will put the bits of code that are creating errors (i think)

Comment: @Puffycheeses At least post something here instead just pasting a link to the code. (And also the link doesn't work.)

Comment: added some but as i said i don't know what the issue is

Comment: @Derek 朕會功夫 and i fixed the link

Comment: @Puffycheeses I'm still getting a 403.

Comment: the download link? or the game?

Comment: Same, 403 on the download link. Perhaps your file is private, or moved to a different link?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/oikj0nyc0hzejc3/AABxeP7YH7wW8nuk9v0K_rY9a?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah... a little does go a long way, especially in programming.

You forgot the curly closing `duckClick`, leaving it undefined.

```
function duckClick(number) {
    ducks = ducks + number;
    document.getElementById("ducks").innerHTML = ducks;
} //This curly brace
```

Comment: I knew it was something stupid. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have just forgot to close the duckClick-function with a } in your main.js file.